# Android app activity navigation

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I made an a app that has seven activities which are all accessed from the main.Each has its own button, but when I click one of the buttons it is starting all the activities can someone solve this issue for me /This is the code:

```
    sat=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button7);
    sun=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    mon=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    tues=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    wed=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
    thurs=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
    fri=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button6);
    info=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button8);

    sat.setOnClickListener(this);
    sun.setOnClickListener(this);
    mon.setOnClickListener(this);
    tues.setOnClickListener(this);
    wed.setOnClickListener(this);
    thurs.setOnClickListener(this);
    fri.setOnClickListener(this);
    info.setOnClickListener(this);





    }

public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int id=arg0.getId();


    if(id==R.id.button6);
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(this,Fri.class));
    }

    if(id==R.id.button5);
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(this,Thurs.class));
    }

    if(id==R.id.button4);
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(this,Wed.class));
    }

    if(id==R.id.button3);
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(this,Tues.class));
    }

    if(id==R.id.button2);
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(this,Mon.class));
    }

    if(id==R.id.button1);
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(this,Sun.class));
    }

    if(id==R.id.button7);
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(this,Sat.class));
    }
```

Comment: Simply use switch case.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plese try below code : solve your problem

```
public void onClick(View arg0)
{
    int id=arg0.getId();
    switch(id)
    {
    case R.id.button6:
         startActivity(new Intent(this,Fri.class));
         break;
    case R.id.button5:
         startActivity(new Intent(this,Thurs.class));
         break;
    case R.id.button4:
         startActivity(new Intent(this,Wed.class));
         break;
    case R.id.button3:
         startActivity(new Intent(this,Tues.class));
         break;
    case R.id.button2:
         startActivity(new Intent(this,Mon.class));
         break;
    case R.id.button1:
         startActivity(new Intent(this,Sun.class));
         break;
    case R.id.button7:
         startActivity(new Intent(this,Sat.class));
         break;
    default:
         break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good one. Please also consider formatting your code. You will find all options in the [Markdown Help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 1):

use `else if` instead of only `if`

or use `switch case` statements in your `onClick`